# How to create a widget with a Text and a list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I'm new to Flutter and I don't get what I'm doing wrong. Following some resources didn't really help me find the issue with the following code :

```
class history_screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const history_screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    DB_Helper db = DB_Helper.instance;
    final rides = Provider.of<AppState>(context).rides;

    if (rides.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.edit_off,
                size: height * 0.04,
              ),
              Text(
                "No history available",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: height * 0.02),
              )
        ],
      )
      );
    }

    return
          RideList(rides: rides);

  }
}
```

So the above code is working and is rendering me or a message `rides.isEmpty` or a list given by `RideList(rides:rides)` if `ride.isEmpty is wrong`.

Now what I want to do is customize the view when it returns the list, in order to add a title and other objects, so I tried :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    DB_Helper db = DB_Helper.instance;
    final rides = Provider.of<AppState>(context).rides;

    if (rides.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.edit_off,
            size: height * 0.04,
          ),
          Text(
            "No history available",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: height * 0.02),
          )
        ],
      ));
    }

    return Center(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "Ride & Track ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: height * 0.02),
        ),
        RideList(rides: rides)
      ],
    ));
  }
```

but the list isn't rendering anymore, and the text isn't centered

[image]

How can I fix this problem ?

[EDIT]

code of RideList:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: rides.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Ride ride = rides[index];
          return RideItem(
            ride: ride,
            onTap: () =>
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
              return RideDetailScreen(
                ride: ride,
                onDelete: () => _removeRide(context, ride),
              );
            })),
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first see why is the issue coming. Basically, Column would try to use the minimum space available and ListView needs an infinite space. So, the column is a constrained widget while the listview needs infinite space. And listview will just use its parent's space.

One way is to make `shrinkWrap: true` and the other way is to wrap ListView with Expanded.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to modify `RideList`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("Title"),
        ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: rides.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Ride ride = rides[index];
              return RideItem(
                ride: ride,
                onTap: () =>
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                  return RideDetailScreen(
                    ride: ride,
                    onDelete: () => _removeRide(context, ride),
                  );
                })),
              );
            }),
        
      ],
    );
  }
```